# How to call server method to list items in a table?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

I have a simple ASP.Net Core 3.0 webapp with SignalR which is used to list and view posts. I added the following js script:

```
"use strict";

const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/PostsHub")
    .withAutomaticReconnect()
    .build();

if (!String.prototype.supplant) {
    String.prototype.supplant = function (o) {
        return this.replace(/{([^{}]*)}/g,
            function (a, b) {
                var r = o[b];
                return typeof r === 'string' || typeof r === 'number' ? r : a;
            }
        );
    };
}

connection.start().then(function () {
    $postsTable = $('#postsTable'),
    $postsTableBody = $postsTable.find('tbody'),
    rowTemplate = '<tr id="{Id}"><td>{Date}</td><td>{User}</td><td><button onclick="btn_click({Id})" id="viewPost{Id}">View</button></td></tr>';

    connection.invoke("getAllPosts").done(function (posts) {
        $postsTableBody.empty();
        $.each(posts, function () {
            $postsTableBody.append(rowTemplate.supplant(this));
        });
    });
}).catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});
```

But with the above code, the posts are not being listed. I can't see where the error is. Could it be the `supplant` function?

Comment: Please post any javascript error you get.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to invoke a hub method that would return all posts, and dynamically populate table with returned data, you can refer to following sample.

*PostsHub Class*

```
public class PostsHub : Hub
{

    public List<Post> GetAllPosts()
    {
        var posts = new List<Post>() {
        new Post(){Id=1,User="feihan",Date="11/25/2019" },
        new Post(){Id=2,User="test1",Date="11/23/2019" },
        new Post(){Id=3,User="test2",Date="11/25/2019" }
        };

        return posts;
    }
}
```

*Post Class*

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

*On JavaScript client*

```
if (!String.prototype.supplant) {
    String.prototype.supplant = function (o) {
        return this.replace(/{([^{}]*)}/g,
            function (a, b) {

                //convert to  lowercase letters
                var r = o[b.toLowerCase()];
                return typeof r === 'string' || typeof r === 'number' ? r : a;
            }
        );
    };
}


connection.start().then(function () {
        $postsTable = $('#postsTable'),
        $postsTableBody = $postsTable.find('tbody'),
        rowTemplate = '<tr id="{Id}"><td>{Date}</td><td>{User}</td><td><button onclick="btn_click({Id})" id="viewPost{Id}">View</button></td></tr>';

    //use connection.invoke(...).then

    connection.invoke("getAllPosts").then(function (posts) {
        $('#postsTable').find('tbody').empty();

        $.each(posts, function () {
            $postsTableBody.append(rowTemplate.supplant(this));
        });
    });
}).catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});
```

*Test Result*

[image]